# prevent select menu to hide page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there any way to stop `selectmenu` to hide active page if screen height is smaller as compare to height of custom `selectmenu` dropdown? i want to show consistent behavior

Thanks and regards

Comment: selectmenu is shown in dialog; dialog hides current page. can you show some code?

Comment: if you reduce page height smaller than dialog then this dialog will behave differently